Can the closure operator arising from a symmetric, anti-reflexive relation be trivial without the relation being maximal?
This question originates from my attempt to study certain closure operators that arise from symmetric, anti-reflexive relations. To be precise, consider a relation $\perp$ on a set $X$ that is symmetric (i.e., $x \perp y$ iff $y \perp x$ for all $x, y \in X$) and anti-reflexive (i.e., $x \not\perp x$ for all $x \in X$). For $A \subset X$, define $A^\perp = \{x \in X: a \perp x, \forall a \in A\}$. Then it is not hard to check that the "double complement" operator $A \mapsto A^{\perp\perp}$ is a closure operator, i.e., $A \subset A^{\perp\perp}$ for all $A \subset X$; $A \subset B$ implies $A^{\perp\perp} \subset B^{\perp\perp}$ for all $A, B \subset X$; and $(A^{\perp\perp})^{\perp\perp} = A^{\perp\perp}$ for all $A \subset X$. As motivating examples, consider,

On a set $X$, let $\perp$ be the maximal symmetric, anti-reflexive relation, i.e., $x \perp y$ iff $x \neq y$. Then the closure operator generated is trivial, i.e., $A^{\perp\perp} = A$ for all $A \subset X$;
Let $X = P(Y) \setminus \{\varnothing\}$ for some set $Y$ with at least two elements,
and where $P(Y)$ is the power set of $Y$. Let $x \perp y$ iff $x \cap y = \varnothing$. (We require $Y$ to have at least two elements as otherwise $X$ is a singleton, this $\perp$ relation is maximal, and it reduces to the first example.) Then $A^{\perp\perp} = P(\cup A) \setminus \{\varnothing\}$;
Let $X$ be a (nonzero) Hilbert space minus the origin, $x \perp y$ be the usual orthogonality relation (i.e., $x \perp y$ iff $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$). Then $A^{\perp\perp} = \overline{\text{span}}(A) \setminus \{0\}$;
Let $X$ be the collection of all Radon probability measures on a locally compact Hausdorff space $\Omega$ with at least two points. Let $x \perp y$ iff $\text{supp}(x) \cap \text{supp}(y) = \varnothing$. (We require $\Omega$ to have at least two points as otherwise $X$ is a singleton, this $\perp$ relation is maximal, and it reduces to the first example.) Then $A^{\perp\perp}$ is the collection of all Radon probability measures $\mu$ on $\Omega$ s.t. $\text{supp}(\mu) \subset \bigcup_{a \in A} \text{supp}(a)$;
Let $X$ be the collection of all normal states on a von Neumann algebra $M$ with $M \neq \mathbb{C}$. Let $x \perp y$ iff $\text{supp}(x) \perp \text{supp}(y)$. (We require $M \neq \mathbb{C}$ as otherwise $X$ is a singleton, this $\perp$ relation is maximal, and it reduces to the first example.) Then $A^{\perp\perp}$ is the collection of all normal states $\varphi$ on $M$ s.t. $\text{supp}(\varphi) \subset \bigvee_{a \in A} \text{supp}(a)$.

In all but the first example above, the closure operator is not trivial. I'm wondering if this is actually necessary, i.e., whether it is the case that, if the closure operator is trivial, then $\perp$ must be maximal. To rephrase the question,

Let $\perp$ be a symmetric, anti-reflexive relation on a set $X$ s.t. $A^{\perp\perp} = A$ for all $A \subset X$. Is it then the case that $x \perp y$ iff $x \neq y$ for all $x, y \in X$?

The answer is true when $X$ is finite. See @Billy's comment below.
For the infinite case, because of the application I have in mind, I'd like the counterexample to be "close" to maximal, in the sense that,

Let $\perp$ be a symmetric, anti-reflexive relation on a set $X$ s.t. $A^{\perp\perp} = A$ and $A^c \setminus A^\perp$ is finite for all $A \subset X$, where $A^c$ is the set-theoretic complement of $A$. Is it then the case that $x \perp y$ iff $x \neq y$ for all $x, y \in X$?

While this seems such an elementary question, for some reason I'm unable to make any dent on it apart from the ridiculously complicated proof for the finite case. I'm assuming I'm simply missing some obvious methods to deal with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is (I think) a sketch proof for the finite case. Let $A\subseteq X$ be arbitrary: then, by anti-reflexivity, $A^\bot \subseteq A^c$. Suppose they're not equal: then $A \cup A^\bot \neq X$, so there exists some $x\in X$ which is not contained in either. Set $B = A\cup {x}$. Then $B^\bot \subsetneq A^\bot$, and so $B\cup B^\bot \neq X$, but $|B^\bot| < |A^\bot|$. So we can iterate this procedure: eventually we will have some $C\subsetneq X$ such that $C^\bot = \varnothing$. But $\varnothing^\bot = X$.

@Billy That's a wonderful argument! I'll edit my post to reflect your comment.

Oh, wait - does this argument work for the general case too? Let $A = X \setminus {x}$: then $A^\bot \subseteq A^c$ must be either ${x}$ or $\varnothing$. But $\varnothing^\bot = X$, so it can't be that, so it must be ${x}$. However, this proves that $x \bot y$ for all $y\in A = X\setminus {x}$, which is what you wanted.

@Billy Ah, you're absolutely right! I knew I must have missed some short and simple argument... I'll accept it if you'd like to write this as an answer.

Let $A = X \setminus \{x\}$ (for arbitrary $x\in X$). We always have $A^\bot \subseteq A^c$, so this gives $A^\bot = \{x\}$ or $A^\bot = \varnothing$. However, $\varnothing^\bot = X$, so it can't be that, and we must have $A^\bot = \{x\}$. This implies that $x\bot y$ for all $y\in A$, i.e. for all $x\neq y$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $\bot$ is maximal.
